# a similar object exists in live mode, but a test mode key was used to make this request. thrown in php

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to make payment in stripe live mode but the following error displayed:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught (Status 400) (Request req_uocWWxAIPTJ6ZR)
>   No such token: tok_1FbZniE3n36TXaJ5sMm5KSsX; a similar object exists
>   in live mode, but a test mode key was used to make this request.
>   thrown in

I have read several tutorials online but still no head-on.

```
 require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_live_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
 $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];


    // Add customer to stripe 
  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array( 
        'email' => $email, 
        'source'  => $token 
    )); 

  // Unique order ID 
    $orderID = strtoupper(str_replace('.','',uniqid('', true))); 

    // Charge a credit or a debit card 
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array( 
        'customer' => $customer->id, 
        'amount'   => $amt, 
        "currency" => "usd",
        'description' => "Payment for ". $rooms, 
        'metadata' => array( 
            'order_id' => $orderID 
        ) 
    )); 

    // Retrieve charge details 
  $chargeJson = $charge->jsonSerialize();
```

Please, what can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you change the publishable key to the live as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error indicates that client-side you used the Live Publishable API key (pk_live_123) to create the Token but server-side you used the Test Secret API key (sk_test_123) to create the Charge.

I know your code shows you are using the Live Secret key but it's definitely not the case. What I'd recommend here is adding logs to your PHP code server-side to ensure that the code you are running is the same as the one you are reading and to confirm you are using the correct API key.